# Comparar una letra con código ascii

Tags: c, ascii, tildes

Intento detectar las letras de cada palabra que tienen tilde. Para esto debo realizar una comparación de la letra con el código ASCII, es decir, comparar la letra seleccionada con ["á","é","í","ó","ú"]. Estas vocales con tilde, poseen una equivalencia en el código ASCII, pero no sé como utilizar esto para realizar la comparación. La idea es ejecutar una operación similar a la siguiente:

```
...
if(palabra[i] == "é"){
   printf("letra con tilde\n");
}
...
```

Comment: No estás comparando con una letra, sino con una cadena. Los caracteres van entre comillas simples (apostrofes). Tú has usado comillas dobles. La comparación debe ser `palabra[i]=='é'` (esto al margen de posibles complicaciones por las codificaciones no ascii, pues las vocales acentuadas _no son ascii_)

Answer (score 1):

### Codificación de caracteres

Las vocales tildadas `áéíóú` no pertenecen a ANSI, así que, para representarlas necesitarás saber la codificación de caracteres que usa tu plataforma objetivo (ASCII, ISO-8859-1, UCS2, UTF-8, UTF-16, etc)

### ASCII

Si tu plataforma objetivo utiliza ASCII, deberás revisar la página de códigos activa, puesto que requerirás una página que defina algunos caracteres del latin (áéíóú, etc), [la página 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) te podría servir (varios OEM la tienen preinstalada para america latina).

### Código

Debido a que muchos utilizan Windows como sistema operativo, utilizaré los pasos para trabajar con ASCII CHCP 850.

El objetivo de este código es comparar la entrada provista por el usuario, a través de la consola.

```c
#include <Windows.h> // para SetConsoleCP, SetConsoleOutputCP
#include <stdio.h> // para printf, fgets, etc
#include <string.h> // parar strcpy


static UINT codePage; // Para guardar la página de códigos anterior
static char buffer[4096]; // Buffer de 4kB (para poder paginarla en x86)

int main () 
{

// Primero debemos preparar la consola
{
    // Obtenemos la página de código ASCII activa en la consola
    codePage = GetConsoleCP();
    if (!codePage) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: No se pudo obtener la pagina de codigos activa\n");
        return -1;      
        }
    
    // Imprimimos la página de código activa
    printf("Info: la pagina de codigo activa es %u\n", codePage);

    // Ahora cambiamos la página de código activa
    
    if (!SetConsoleCP(850) || !SetConsoleOutputCP(850)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: No se pudo cambiar la pagina de codigos activa\n");
        return -1;          
    }
}
    
// Ahora cuando leas información de la consola, se te enviará como ASCII 850
{
    // Solicitamos una palabra al usuario
    printf("Ingrese una palabra: ");

    // Leemos la línea entera de la entrada
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);

    // Eliminamos el salto de linea en el buffer
    buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0';

    // Obtenemos el tamaño de la cadena a comparar
    int length = strlen(buffer);

    // Creamos una nueva cadena, se necesita un caracter más para guardar el caracter nulo '\0'
    char palabra[length + 1];

    // Copiamos los bytes del buffer a la recien creada cadena  
    strcpy(palabra, buffer);
    
    // Vemos si tiene tildes
    char c;
    int i = 0, tieneTildes = 0;
    while (!tieneTildes && (c = palabra[i++]) != '\0') {
        // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850
        switch(c) {
        case '\xa0': case '\xb5':  // 'á' y 'Á'
        case '\x82': case '\x90':  // 'é' y 'É'
        case '\xa1': case '\xd6':  // 'í' e 'Í'
        case '\xa2': case '\xe0':  // 'ó' y 'Ó'
        case '\xa3': case '\xe9':  // 'ú' y 'Ú'
            tieneTildes = 1;
        }
    }

    if (tieneTildes) {
        printf("la palabra \"%s\" contiene tildes\n", palabra);
    } else {
        printf("la palabra \"%s\" NO contiene tildes\n", palabra);
    }
}
    

// Finalmente restauramos la página de códigos original
{
    SetConsoleCP(codePage);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(codePage);
}
    return 0;
}
```

**NOTA**
En windows, trabajar con aplicaciones multi-idioma, a través de ANSI-C es un dolor de huevos, como puedes ver, tuvimos que acudir a las funciones `SetConsoleCP` y `SetConsoleOutputCP`. En este caso, fue sencillo, debido a que solo íbamos a trabajar con la consola, y con una sola página de códigos. En caso de necesitar más páginas (aplicación multi-idioma) se requerirá usar sí o sí las funciones UNICODE de windows, en lugar de las ANSI-C

Answer (score -2):

Te recomiendo que hagas el siguiente bucle para identificar que valores numéricos van con cada respectivo caracter:

```
char c;

for(int i=32;i<256;i++){

c=i;

cout<<c<<endl;

}
```

Otra cosa a comentar es que cuando comparas o asignas un caracter a una variable de tipo caracter, debe estar en comillas simples. Ejemplo:

```
char letra='a';

letra='b';

if(letra=='b')cout<<"La letra es b";
```

Si haces lo siguiente:

```
char letra="a";
```

Tendrás un error

Un truco que puedes utilizar para saber que valor numérico corresponde a cierto caracter es el siguiente:

```
int num='A'; //cambia este caracter para obtener resultados

cout<<num;
```

Con ese código puedes probar diferentes caracteres.
Por último, recuerda que no en todos los programas están incluidos las letras con tilde y es probable que estén suplantadas por otros caracteres(como en mi caso donde uso Windows), así que no te asustes si encuentras símbolos raros en vez de letras con tildes.